# HP DL385p G8 p420i not detecting additional drives

Tags: raid, hpe

I have a dl385 g8 with the p420i radi controller. I went through a lot of steps upgrading the server firmware to the latest, rapid controller and iLo. After a lot of work I was able to boot the the intelligent provisioning and access the raid arrays.

I currently already have 2 logical volumes made up of 6 x 1.2 TB 6/Gbs 10k SAS drives. One runs the OS and the other is a data store housing vms.

I purchased 6 more drives of the same specs, 1.2TB, etc. they light up fine with the spinning activity wheel but the disk icon stays off telling me they are not part of the array. In the raid configuration though I do not see any unassigned drives like I have not installed them so I cannot create an additional array. I verified the controller has the 512 mb cache so it can have up to 64 and house many more disks. Is there something I have to do to get these drives recognized. Also not trying to lose all my current data. The circles drives are the original I have been running for about 1 year or so.  [server pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3f1h.jpg)

EDIT:
Looks like the drives show in the intelligent provisioning but show as follows
1.2TB 0 RPM SAS

So the drives are being read but not sure why this speed and unable to see them in unassigned drives.

Comment: did you get the HDDs brand new ? or used?

Comment: No they are all refurbished from a reputable company. I could understand if one or two of those drives may have malfunctioned but all 6? Would any array meta data affect them being detected?

Comment: make sure to mark all the purchased hdds as "Unconfigured Good". this can be done on other server. I Assume that these HDDs been into raid previously and they marked.

Comment: If they have been in a raid array, I am assuming, with one server I would have to rebuild my arrays. I am already prepping for this by backing up my data offsite.

Comment: with high percentage those were in raid previously and haven't been marked as clean

Comment: From the picture, your six new disks have four different sizes: 146/300/900/2400 GB. That doesn't match "of the same specs, 1.2TB" and (IMHO) "from a reputable company". I wonder what ADU tells about those drives.